# Running asp.net MVC without building or publishing to a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I just wondered if its possible to run a asp.net MVC site without building or publishing.

I've used webforms on my server before with out needed to build or publish the code, just wondered if it was possible to do this with MVC.

My Server if you want to know is windows server 2012 r2 if that helps at all.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, that's not possible, you will at least need to build the source code for your controllers into a .NET assembly.

Comment: You may be using a website project before. That has a build process, but mostly it's hidden. It also suffers from a number of issues that the web application project and MVC help avoid by not using the dynamic compilation. You don't have to publish to the server. You can publish to a folder on your local computer then upload to the server however you want. The publish process is good though as it allows for you to add automated checks or other activities into the deployment process.

Comment: You can do a copy deployment with the new ASP .NET Core 1.0 MVC 6 edition but you still have to run dnx on the server. It's not possible with older versions however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible.
You cant run asp.net MVC without  building the source code.

Comment: Thanks, just couldn't find a definite answer anywhere else. Thanks for clearing that up!